# Set of elements outside range space

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix T
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&2\\1&2&4&1\\1&-3&-1&7\\2&1&5&4\end{bmatrix}

The range space of matrix T is denoted by V, and the set of elements that doesn't belong to V is denoted by W.
Q: Determine if W is a vector space and show that if vector \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} belongs to W then 8x-5y-z-t≠0

So i RREF T to get \begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
How do i proceed from here? Thanks

Comment: If you don't know what to do next, perhaps back up and ask: Why did you RREF T?

Comment: $W$ can't be a vector space. One way to see this is to note that every vector space must contain a zero-vector

Comment: I rref to find the span. Is it because V contains the null vector therefore W doesn't? How did 8x-5y-z-t come abt? Thanks alot